# how to fix rusted grill legs

Tags: appliances

Can someone please help me figure out how do I fix my grill legs? They are rusted and right now the bottom port is on top of couple of bricks. It works but I would like to fix it with something that does not get rusted easily/quickly. What tools/posts can I use to fix it? I don't really need wheels attached to the legs.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: By the time you fix it with stainless steel, it's cheaper to scrap it and replace it with one made from stainless steel, most of the time. You can weld on or bolt on new plain steel, but it will rust again.

Answer (score 5):

Make a rectangle out of pressure treated lumber (2x4 on edge). Put screws through the legs and bottom plate into wood.

Answer (score 3):

cut the legs off at the top and put the (shortened) grill on an outdoor table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can almost completely restore, including the wheels.

The bottom part of that frame does not look healthy and it wont last long.

The rod for the wells is also looks End of Life.

You can replace the rod with anything (of the size) you find in hardware store and use special slip resistant washers, to keep the wheels in place.

[image: washers]

Get some 2x4 pressure treated wood, and screw it underneath the bottom plate. Now fasten the wheels rod to it with simple cable holders.

[image: clips]

On the other side without wheels, just screw in some screws of appropriate length into the 2x4 wood.